# Prepared statement error. Newbie issue

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I can't figure out what is wrong with these few lines:

```
    if  ( $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->num_rows == 1;
    )           

    {
    $errors[] = "Username is taken.";
    }
```

Comment: do you have it wrapped up in a try/catch? you can see some helpful info here in how to get error messages from pdo. http://prash.me/php-pdo-and-prepared-statements/

Comment: The syntax is totally invalid?

Comment: @JimL wrappin in a try/catch is a double pointless here, mind you. It is pointless to wrap every statement in try catch in general, and especially with default mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you got your other code, but I think you want something like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($res);

if($stmt->num_rows == 1)
{
    $errors[] = "Username is taken.";
}
```

There's an unnecessary fetch in your original code, also

Answer (score 0):

```
if($stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1'))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $errors[] = "Username $username is taken.";
    }
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}
```